# React MUI X Data Grid. Server side sortingMode returning empty array on unsort

Tags: material-ui, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

So this seems to be by design (see this PR https://github.com/mui/mui-x/pull/7125/files ) but It's thrown a spanner in my logic that I can't get my head around.

Basically when I call `handleSortModelChange` that updates my state and at the same time calls a function `reloadData` that triggers the request to the back end to fetch the correct data.

To clarify, I am sorting ALL of the data in the table, not just the 20 results that are displayed. And as there may be 50k plus results it doesn't seem right to fetch everything in one request on page load.

Now the problem is that when I try to sort my columns, everything is fine when I sort by `asc` or `desc` but when you cycle through to the 3rd option (unsort). the component returns an empty array and this breaks the page. I'll clarify below.

here is `handleSortModelChange`:

```
const [sortModel, setSortModel] = useState<GridSortModel>([
    {
      field: "review_date",
      sort: "desc",
    },
  ]);

  const handleSortModelChange = (model: GridSortModel) => {
    if (JSON.stringify(model) !== JSON.stringify(sortModel)) {
      setSortModel(model);
      reloadData(0, model[0].field, model[0].sort, searchValue);
    }
  };
```

you can see already what the problem is, when the `model` array is empty, then `model[0].field, model[0].sort` are undefined.

Now i tried to check if the array was empty and pass null values instead whilst still having an object in the array:

```
  const handleSortModelChange = (model: GridSortModel) => {
    if (JSON.stringify(model) !== JSON.stringify(sortModel)) {
      if (model.length <= 0) {
        setSortModel([
          {
            // use the existing field name rather than look for something being passed to the function
            field: sortModel[0].field, 
            sort: null,
          },
        ]);
        reloadData(0, null, null, searchValue);
      } else {
        setSortModel(model);
        reloadData(0, model[0].field, model[0].sort, searchValue);
      }
    }
  };
```

that gets around the page exploding on unsort but then it doesn't actually unsort.

has anyone encountered this problem before? My gut is telling me that the way `reloadData` works is flawed but it seems weird to me that `DataGrid` would look for an array item OR `null` for sorting behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I solved the problem without noticing. I was sorting by date which was already sorted by `desc` and cycling through to the 'unsorted' state was exactly the same as the initial state so it just looked like nothing was happening.

Hope this helps anyone else who runs into this issue!